# Should I use oil primer underneath oil paint?

Tags: painting, primer, alkyd

Is it necessary to use oil primer underneath oil paint (for trim) or can I use latex primer?
Do all primers work interchangeably with oil and latex paints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule of thumb is you can use latex paints over oil primers and latex primers. Do not use oil based paints over any surface currently coated with a latex primer or paint.  The oil based paint or primer will usually lift the latex product and leave you with a wrinkled surface that looks like alligator skin.

Comment: If we cannot use oil primer over previously latex-painted trim do we have to use latex primer?  We are not fans of latex primer.

Comment: You cannot use oil over latex, so you are stuck with latex.  Oil primer will most likely raise the latex paint.

Comment: Why are you not fond of latex primers? What are you trying to cover?

Comment: We were told oil primer provides better adhesion.  We will be priming all trim, doors and cabinets.  We want to prevent old-house odors and stain bleed-through, and also want good adhesion.  We will be using an oil topcoat.  NOTE: We lightly sanded all surfaces in preparation for priming.

Comment: Oil is fine if you can still find it. Due to the VOC laws, many paint companies don't offer it anymore. Getting harder to find every day.  The improvement in acrylic based paints can rival oil, especially some high fill cabinet grade enamels from Sherwood Williams and Ben Moore.

Comment: In old work and over dark woods, I have had great results with pigmented shellac as a primer, sanded it is a fantastic base for latex paints. It is the best stain and odor blocker out there. We use it on burn jobs, pet urine damaged sub floors etc. It dries in no time. Clean up with denatured alcohol.

Comment: You mention acrylic paints...I am somewhat confused by the different types of paints.  Would you please explain how acrylic is different from a basic latex, and what are the benefits of acrylic over basic latex?  We have used Shellac in the past in areas that had severe nicotine stains, due to your recommendation...thanks. This time we will use a regular primer.

Comment: acrylic is the main and most expensive component in latex paint. Latex is almost a misnomer as there is little latex or water in "latex" paint. It is water soluble, but should never be thinned with water. the higher the percentage of pigments and acrylic in the paint, the higher the quality and usually the price.   glad you had success with the Bins pigmented shellac.

Comment: So should 'latex' be used on ceilings and a good acrylic be used on walls in general? I have been confused because I hear the term acrylic and enamel...and never know which one to use where (I am referring to water-based enamels).  Does water-based enamel simply suggest the sheen?

Comment: Generally speaking, enamels are a hard finish, usually glossy. they tend to be a higher quality with a more durable finish. Latex is using the term enamel alot now for the harder curing paints. I like enamels in rental properties for wear resistance, but I don't like the gloss on walls and never suggest it to a normal use residential customer. I like eggshell or satin for walls.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Newer paints/primers hold up a lot better.  You need to check the manufacturers website.  The biggest issue you will have with a latex primer is that it will need to be pretty far in the curing process to paint over it - meaning it could be a month or two.  Again you need to check the individual manufacturer's website.